Module "gitlab-runner" (from ../gitlab_runner/main.tf:44) cannot be found │ in the module registry at registry.terraform.io
Getting below error when running gitlab pipeline, is it required to re-register the GitLab runner.
Module "gitlab-runner" (from ../gitlab_runner/main.tf:44) cannot be found
│ in the module registry at registry.terraform.io.


Hello you'll have to provide more content of your main.tf file, the command you run etc.. In the current state it's impossible to help you.

forgot to update here that the issue was solved by replacing the runner with https://registry.terraform.io/modules/SwiftEngineer/gitlab-runner/aws/latest

replacing with other runner solved the issue.
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/SwiftEngineer/gitlab-runner/aws/latest
